# Grails atmosphere plugin browser hang after few requests

Tags: java, grails, atmosphere

Using atmosphere plugin in grails, after a few requests to server (after few pages of navigation) the browser is not rendering any pages and it is just loading. Other browser in other systems works fine. The code to connect to the server is placed in common layout page.
server code:

```
def onRequest = { event ->
    def userBroadcasters= ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute('userBroadcasters')
    def uid=event.getRequest().session.user?.id
    if(!userBroadcasters){
        userBroadcasters=[:]
    }
    Broadcaster privateChannel = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/userChannel"+uid, true);
    privateChannel.addAtmosphereResource(event)
    userBroadcasters.put(uid,privateChannel)
    ServletContextHolder.servletContext.setAttribute('userBroadcasters',userBroadcasters)
    event.suspend()
    //println ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute('userBroadcasters')
    //println "Inside onRequest!"
}
```

client code in common layout:

```
function callback(response) {
            if (response.status == 200 && response.responseBody.length > 0) {
               //action
            }
        }

        var location = '${request.contextPath}/atmosphere/mx';
        var request = {transport: "streaming", fallbackTransport: 'long-polling', contentType: "application/json",connectTimeout:4000};
        $.atmosphere.subscribe(location, callback, request);
```